# Eevee fire and smoke issues

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I have run into a problem, fire and smoke won't work, I have volumetric on in the render tab and [you can see my fluid settings in the video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1btp3gYG_3Z1sTQ4A-9Q2gvOKpqqeLMlF).

I have tried cycles and fiddled the hell out of the render settings in EEVEE, I have done a ton of stuff to get it to work. When I make a new file to test fire and smoke  by itself it works sometimes but when I test in my main project file with my rocket, it never shows in rendered or viewport.

I've re-baked so many times. If you want my project file i can attach that.

I am hoping someone will be able to provide a solution that works.

Comment: What's your question? Is your question how to render fire and smoke using eevee? Or how to simulate the smoke properly. Also please explain what you've tried exactly. Might be a good idea providing a file.  Please take your time and read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and I suggest to put a bit more effort into your question to get an answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: So all I’m asking is how to fix the fluid simulation and smoke + fire. It doesn’t doesn’t show up in rendered or viewport. Watch the video I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I switched it to replay and it worked! I am going to just do it in final mode as well because that works too. for some reason modular doesn't work.